# How to get OS X Server (for OS X Mavericks) for free (as Mac or iOS Developer)?

Tags: macos, ios, server.app, developer-program

The Server.app for OS X Mavericks has a price tag of $19.99. Some websites mention it to be free for Developers who joined as iOS Developer or Mac Developer.

How do I get the redemption code for the OS X Server.app on Mavericks?

---

Here are two Articles on the topic:

[Apple promoting automated continuous integration to iOS developers, providing free OS X Server copies](http://9to5Mac.com/2013/10/24/apple-promoting-automated-continuous-integration-to-ios-developers-providing-free-os-x-server-copies/) | 9to5Mac.com

[A power user’s guide to OS X Server, Mavericks edition](http://arstechnica.com/apple/2013/12/a-power-users-guide-to-os-x-server-mavericks-edition/) | Ars Technica

Comment: They have since removed OS X Server from the downloads lists. Just an FYI.

Comment: @m3g4hur7z It is still available, as per Alexandru Drancas answer, in the OSX Dev Center.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

[9 To Mac](http://9to5mac.com/2013/10/24/apple-promoting-automated-continuous-integration-to-ios-developers-providing-free-os-x-server-copies/) states this clearly:

> To download OS X Server, developers should access the iOS or Mac developer portal to retrieve an App Store redemption code.

1. **If you have iOS development program go to:**
   https://developer.apple.com/osx/download/
2. Scroll down
3. Click **Get download code**
4. Redeem the code
5. Download your free version of OS X Server 3.0.3

This text is next to the button:

> OS X Server 3.0.3 Includes Xcode Server to enable continuous
>   integration. Works with Xcode 5 to configure bots that automatically
>   build and test your apps. Requires OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Same is now available for Yosemite

Comment: Well what do you know, I get a $20 app free for paying $100 a year.

Answer (score 1):

For some reason I don't get it on the iOS website but you can get it on the OS X [OSX Dev Center](https://developer.apple.com/osx/download/) and down you have the code.